# Lim inf and lim sup

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for 
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \inf \left(-1 +\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n$$
and 
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sup \left(-1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n$$
My idea is to factorise $(-1)^n$ and determine the limit of

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n$$

But I have difficulties finding the limit of that expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ given by:
$$ a_n = \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n $$
converges towards $1$, the only accumulation points of the set $\{(-1)^n a_n\}$ are $-1$ and $+1$, so $\liminf=-1$ and $\limsup=+1$. To prove the first statement, it is sufficient to use squeezing:
$$1-\frac{1}{n}\leq \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n\leq 1-\frac{1}{n^2}.$$
The first inequality follows from the Bernoulli's inequality, the second one is trivial.